# ATT Smart Home Manager "Network Attack Blocked" on server computer?

Tags: networking

I am a bit out my league here, as I am not versed in, well, really anything about network, but recently I have realized for the past ~15 days, I have gotten around 10 AT&T warnings that a network attack was blocked on my Windows 10 server for my home.

These are the IP addresses it is warning me of:

```
45.55.0.19
162.243.145.16
192.241.207.93
192.241.222.29
192.241.198.9
198.199.112.86
192.241.193.50
178.128.151.41
5.39.220.78 
212.83.8.79
```

Now, I'm not sure if these are false positives, or a genuine "attack" on my network that I need to bring attention to. These all came in over the last 15 days at varying times, even when I was asleep not online at all.

All of them except the last 2 seem to be coming from "DigitalOcean LLC" which seems to be either a datacenter or VPN (IP lookup I'm using doesn't specify). The last 2 are coming back as being not from the US, or "DigitalOcean LLC". I'm not sure if those are related to the others. The last one is coming back as from Russia, which, is honestly a big red flag from me.

The only applications I have running on my server is Chrome Remote Desktop and Python (and some installed modules), as well as pre-installed Windows 10/Lenovo drivers. Also to note, the python script includes pulling a file from Gitlab.

So, my ATT firewall is doing its job, but I would still like to know if this is something that I should/can stop. I have had multiple devices, including windows 10, and have never had this happen. Sorry if this post is kind of jumbled, just curious about this situation and would like to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

Those "***blocked attacks***" are indeed real attempts that were blocked. But they are unlikely (or rather, certainly not) targeted attacks *attacking your network*, but rather general scans run (mostly by bad guys, but also by legitimate companies that are tracking vulnerabilities) all over the internet to find vulnerable devices out there (and if found, potentially exploit them.)

You can look up those IPs on services like https://www.abuseipdb.com/ and https://threatbook.io/ and you'll see that those are scanners scanning all over the internet (hitting many honeypots.)

This (attracting those bots to scan your IP) is not something that is necessarily caused by you doing anything, but it's possible that it would be caused if you posted your IP anywhere on the internet, or if you opened any ports (port forwarding on the router) to devices on your netowrk.

If **1)** Your router is up-to-date with the firmware, **2)** You don't have any fort forwarding open (or you do, and it's only to specific devices that you know to be safe), (**3)** You search your own network public IP with something like https://www.shodan.io/ and nothing shows up), then I would not be worried.